# How to use return in for loop with function in python

Tags: python, return

I have function like this

```
def get(l):
   if l.a == 8 :
       return "foo"
   if l.a == 9 :
       return "bar"
```

Now i have for loop

```
for l in mylist:
   value = get(l)
return value
```

I want that for loop should exit if my function return something and if it does not then it should continue with next loop item untill my function return something.

I can do that if my put my function logic in for loop but i don't want to do that

Comment: What should happen if the function never returns anything (ie. just `None`) for every item?

Comment: Why does the question have `django` tag, is it related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`l` is a poor choice for a variable as it looks too similar to `1` in some fonts. I changed it to `item` here

```
for item in mylist:
    value = get(item)
    if value is not None
        break
# ... can do other stuff with value here
return value
```

or even

```
for item in mylist:
    value = get(item)
    if value is not None:
        return value
```

if you don't need to do anything else after the loop

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for l in mylist:
   value = get(l)
   if value is not None:
       return value
   else: 
       continue
```

Comment: Shouldn't need to `return` and `break`: just the `return` will do. Some might say the `else: continue` is superfluous, but I don't mind it so much, since it's explicit.

Comment: I like to include the `else: continue` more for the traceability benefit of new learners. Just something I think to be helpful.

Comment: I agree, I'm not for or against it, really. I guess I was anticipating the criticisms of others :).

Comment: It's a quick to criticize lot, aint it ;)